# How to implement DataTable with parameter 'id' in Laravel (DataTables)?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, datatables

I am trying to pass the ID value from the blade file into ajax so it the data table will be routed and will call the `ProductActivities` function in `ProductController`.

Here's my snippet code for `show()` function in `ProductController`:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $product = Product::find($id);
    $data = Product::with(['user_modify'], 'id', $product->user_modified)
                    ->where('product_id', '=', $id)->first();
                    
    $category = Category::select('category_name')
                        ->where('category_id', '=', $data->product_type)
                        ->pluck('category_name')
                        ->first();

    if($data->count() > 0){
        return view('product.view', compact('data', 'category'));
    }else{
        Toastr::error('Product cannot be retrieved.', 'Error');
        return view('product.index');
    }
}
```

And here's the snippet code of JavaScript for the DataTable initialization in `view.blade.php` file:

```
@push('js')
<script>
  $(function () {
    
    $("#prod_log_tbl").DataTable({
      responsive:true,
      stateSave:false,
      scrollY:true,
      autoWidth: false,
      ajax: {{ url('product/activities', [Request::segment(3)]) }},
      order:[0, 'desc'],
      searchable: false, 
      sortable:false,
      fixedColumns: true
    });
  });
  </script>
@endpush
```

line of code for route in `web.php`:

```
Route::get('product/activities/{id}', 'Master\ProductController@ProductActivities')->name('product/activities/{id}');
```

snippet code for the `ProductActivities()` function in `ProductController`:

```
public function ProductActivities($id)
{
    $dataAct = Activity::all()->where('subject_id', '=', $id);
    return Datatables::of($dataAct)->make(true);
}
```

And here's the result of my current progress:

[image]

In the screenshot of result the URL that ajax shows has additional values after the ID which I think causes of the DataTable error.

I don't know How I am getting this error? **How can I implement the passing of ID from the view blade file through `DataTable` ajax into the `ProductController`?**

P.S. I use Yajra/DataTable package for Laravel.

Comment: Datatables accept collection, not the model instance, you need to make collection `$data = Product::with(['user_modify'], 'id', $product->user_modified)
                    ->where('product_id', '=', $id)->get();` and this one `$dataAct = Activity::where('subject_id', '=', $id)->get();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you do not need php echo in you Ajax url, [route helper](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-route) syntax is

```
{{ route('routeName', ['id' => 1]) }}
```

you need route name and parameter, another way is using [url helper](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-url)

```
{{ url('product/activities/', [Request::segment(3)]) }}
```

Beside this if you want to use model refer [documentation](https://datatables.yajrabox.com/eloquent/basic), `using first()` will give you only one object, you need a collection, better considering `get()`.

Comment: gives me this error in javascript: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':' and this output in the url became: ajax: http://127.0.0.1:8000/product/activities/104,

Comment: @Taguro unexpected token comes because of some syntax error, please post your updated code and also what is the expected url let me know.

Comment: updated my code for view blade file (DataTable initialization)

Comment: @Taguro It seems you need to wrap your url with quotes. `"{{ url('product/activities', [Request::segment(3)]) }}"` because you are assigning a string here.